# Find the normal to the function

Tags: functions

Good day everyone, I think my teacher had made a mistake in a answer. She claims that this function cannot have normal that is parallel to $y=2x+7$

$f(x)=\ln(x+1)$

In my calculations it has : $y=-\frac{1}{2}x -\frac{1}{4} + \ln\frac{1}{2} $

Can you ansure me that it has ?

Comment: but your straight line is not orthogonal to the given line

Comment: Have you tried sketching a diagram? Always useful when geometric things are in doubt.

Comment: You are looking for a normal parallel to the given line, not perpendicular to it, which would make the tangent parallel to the given line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher is correct.

The derivative of the function $f(x)$ is $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}, x\geq -1$.
The normal to $y=2x+7$ has a derivative of $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Since $x\geq -1$, there is no solution to $x$ which makes $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}=-\frac{1}{2}$.